# See the output of a scheduled task in the terminal

Tags: command-line, schedule, at-command

Is it possible to see the outputs of tasks, that are schedule with "at" in real-time? Say, I want to see the values of my loss function as I train my network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [my post on Super User](https://superuser.com/a/1164493/334516), obtain the PID of the `at` job and then you could see where `at` is saving the output:

```
$ at now
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
at> sleep 10m
at> <EOT>
job 7 at Sat Jan  7 20:18:00 2017
$ pgrep sleep
7582
$ ls -l /proc/7582/fd
total 0
lr-x------ 1 muru muru 64 Jan  7 20:19 0 -> /var/spool/cron/atjobs/a0000701795998 (deleted)
lrwx------ 1 muru muru 64 Jan  7 20:19 1 -> /var/spool/cron/atspool/a0000701795998
lrwx------ 1 muru muru 64 Jan  7 20:19 2 -> /var/spool/cron/atspool/a0000701795998
```

As you can see, the output is saved to a temp file, which you can now check:

```
$ sudo tail -f /var/spool/cron/atspool/a0000701795998
Subject: Output from your job        7
To: muru
```

You need `sudo` because the containing directory is not world-accessible (at least on Ubuntu 14.04):

```
$ sudo namei -lx /var/spool/cron/atspool/a0000701795998
f: /var/spool/cron/atspool/a0000701795998
Drwxr-xr-x root     root   /
drwxr-xr-x root     root   var
drwxr-xr-x root     root   spool
drwxr-xr-x root     root   cron
drwxrwx--T daemon   daemon atspool
-rw------- muru     muru   a0000701795998
```