# Running pwd command by using at - at doesn't do anything

Tags: at-command

I'm trying to learn how to use the `at` command and to do that I tried to run the `pwd` command, but it seems that nothing happens:

[image]

How can I run a command like `pwd` by using `at`?

Comment: What was it supposed to do according to you?

Comment: Hello @muru I expect that the command at prints (now) the current path because I specified pwd. Did I misunderstand the goal of the command?

Comment: Well, yes. At runs the command at some time in the future; it doesn't run it on the terminal where you ran `at` - that terminal might not even be around at that future time. Where will it print to?

Comment: @muru how can I see the output of the command?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/82838/70524 - if you have mailing set up, the output is mailed. Otherwise if the command runs long enough, try https://askubuntu.com/a/894889/158442 while it is running

Comment: @muru thank you for the suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output is not made in your current terminal window. You need to send it somewhere. For example to a log file, via Email, ...

```
pwd >> pwd.log
```

Then you can check the output:

```bsh
cat pwd.log
#or
tail -f pwd.log
```

Comment: Thank you very much @pLumo for your simple and extremely clear explanation.